# Updating a particular value (common in all tables) together using Coredata

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have many tables in my coredata structure. All entities have a common attribute called `is_sync` with a default value of 0. Now on the click of a `sync` button elsewhere in the app, I want to update the value of `is_sync` in all the tables from 0 to 1. How can I achieve this...?

An example of how I updated a value in a single table (for a different scenario) was like so...

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NewProduct> = NewProduct.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "sku = %@", dfg!)

     do {

         let array_categories = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
         let cat = array_categories[0]

          cat.setValue(false, forKey: "isAddToCartVar")
          try managedContext.save()

        } catch let error as NSError {
             print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
         }
```

But how can I update a value common in all tables together(like I've explained in the question) ...?

Comment: As per your functionality Add a attribute is_sync in unique table like profile then when you sync that profile is_sync value will be 0 to 1.

Comment: all tables have the `is_sync` value and sync happens on all tables together. So I want to update the value of `is_sync` of all tables together...

Comment: If you want to make the same update on every instance, look into `NSBatchUpdateRequest`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can possibly Use this to update the Flag in **Core Data**:

```
func update(){
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "SyncData")
    do{
        let results = try context.fetch(request)

        if results.count > 0{
            for result in results as! [NSManagedObject]{
                if let is_SyncFlag = result.value(forKey: "is_sync") {
                    if is_SyncFlag == 0{
                        result.setValue(1, forKey: "is_sync")
                        do{
                            try context.save()
                        }
                        catch{
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch{
    }
}
```

This you can Do for Every Table in a common Function

Comment: Yes, Like You can make a common re-Usable Function that can be called each and every time for all the Tables Common. This was just a demo code for You reference as i don't know how you are using

Comment: @v.bw If it Helped you please approve this.

Comment: Absolutely @Abhirajsinh Thakore. If it works, I'll accept and also upvote your answer...

Comment: Yes @v.bw If u stuck at any Point Feel free to ask.

Comment: It worked @Abhirajsinh Thakore. Thanks a lot. Have given an upvote also..:)

Comment: My pleasure @v.bw pleasure to help you